# how to solve 401 unauthorized error in postman when calling a .Net API

Tags: authentication, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

[image: header calculated in postman]
I have a .net core webapi working fine and tested with swagger, also the method has set to allow anonymous access so no authentication should be required. But when testing the POST method with Postman, I always get the 401 error.. Appreciate any help!

Comment: How is your POST method API set to allow anonymous access? Can you provide your specific configuration and your API code?

Comment: It can also be helpful to post a copy of a sample JWT access token to the question. ASP.NET Core also do provide good looing that can give you good access to why it fails.

Comment: @Chaodeng the method has [allowanonymous] guard and in startup file, and in launchSettings.json, "anonymousAuthentication": true,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am not clear about your specific code implementation, I wrote a demo here, which is an example of generating token from user login to access permission API. You can refer to it, maybe it will help you a little:

First,open the appsettings.json file and change the section named Jwt:

```
"Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "testUser",
    "Audience": "user",
    "Key": "this is my custom Secret key for authnetication"
  }
```

Enable the JWT authentication scheme and swagger authorization configuration when the configuration starts, the entire code is as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using WebApplication129.Controllers.conf;

namespace WebApplication129
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
            services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
     .AddJwtBearer(options =>
     {
         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
             ValidateIssuer = true,
             ValidateAudience = true,
             ValidateLifetime = true,
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
             ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
             IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
         };
     });
            services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.Add(new GroupingByNamespaceConvention());
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
            {   
                config.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description =
        "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer",
                    BearerFormat="JWT"
                });

                config.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            },
            Scheme = "oauth2",
            Name = "Bearer",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,

        },
        new List<string>()
    }
});


                var titleBase = "Test API";
                var description = "This is a Web API for Test operations";
                var TermsOfService = new Uri("https://xxxxxx");
                var License = new OpenApiLicense()
                {
                    Name = "MIT"
                };
                var Contact = new OpenApiContact()
                {
                    Name = "Test",
                    Email = "Test@hotmail.com",
                    Url = new Uri("https://xxxxxx")
                };

                config.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = titleBase + " v1",
                    Description = description,
                    TermsOfService = TermsOfService,
                    License = License,
                    Contact = Contact
                });

                config.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v2",
                    Title = titleBase + " v2",
                    Description = description,
                    TermsOfService = TermsOfService,
                    License = License,
                    Contact = Contact
                });

                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                config.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
        }

       
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(config =>
            {
                config.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test v1");
                //config.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "Test v2");
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Log in and generate the jwt part as follows. Since I did not use it with a database, I customized a user:

Model:

```
public class Usuario
    {
        public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication129.Model;

namespace WebApplication129.Controllers.V1
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SegurancaController : Controller
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;
        public SegurancaController(IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            _config = Configuration;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] Usuario loginDetalhes)
        {
            bool resultado = ValidarUsuario(loginDetalhes);
            if (resultado)
            {
                var tokenString = GerarTokenJWT();
                return Ok(new { token = tokenString });
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }
        private string GerarTokenJWT()
        {
            var issuer = _config["Jwt:Issuer"];
            var audience = _config["Jwt:Audience"];
            var expiry = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120);
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: issuer, audience: audience,
expires: expiry, signingCredentials: credentials);
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var stringToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            return stringToken;
        }
        private bool ValidarUsuario(Usuario loginDetalhes)
        {
            if (loginDetalhes.NomeUsuario == "TestName" && loginDetalhes.Senha == "TestPwd")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test and verify API:

```
 [ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add the description information you need    
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// 
    [Route("test")]
   [HttpGet]
    
    public string Test( int userID)
    {
        return "v1 test";
    }

    [Route("list_data")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public Object  Data()
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.id = 1;
        user.userName = "Test";
        user.email = "test@xxx.com";
        user.address = "testAddress";

        return user;
    }

}
```

The above shows two APIs, one requires authorization and the other does not require authorization to access.

Resutl:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the detailed example. Appreciate this, although my mistake was not including the correct JWT bearer token when using Postman

Answer (score 0):

Still If anyone can't figure out the error after @Tupac answer, check that you have included proper

- app.UseAuthentication();
- app.UseAuthorization();

in Program.cs file